# What meta tag should I use for a dictionary?

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags, microformats

I have a web site that serves as a dictionary, and it ranks good at google when searching for a rare word in my language (the dictionary target). I want the result to appear in the `define: some-word`, as well as in the search results when someone uses the filter tool `Dictionary`.

Should I add some special meta-tag in the head of the html?

Does google have a special webmaster tool for registering dictionaries like:
 `wordnetweb.princeton.edu` or `en.wiktionary.org` ?

Comment: Not programming related. Perhaps webmasters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't know how far outside of its typical PageRank algorithm Google goes for dictionary/definition based sites you might want to start researching microformats for word definition and dictionaries.

Looks like some work has been done via: http://microformats.org/wiki/definition-examples but I have no idea how widely accepted/implemented that standard might be by Google or others.